# How do I scan a single file with Windows Defender?

Tags: windows, windows-8, anti-virus

The number one way people are used to using virus scanners is by scanning a single file.

The number one OS viruses are found on is Windows.

Microsoft's official virus scanner, Windows Defender, seems to be missing the most common use case.

How do I scan a file with Windows Defender? Is it impossible to do?

Okay, there is a "Custom Scan" feature which is poorly implemented, takes forever to click through and find my file. So that's not very helpful.

You might say, "well, just turn real-time protection on" -- but that may work for the average use case. But what if I have a emulator that is responsible for running a file, and so the file isn't being ran through a normal process? Or what if I am simply delivering a file to another computer off the network, and I can't run it on this machine for compatibility reasons? There's many reasons why that approach is not sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [add the Windows Defender in Context Menu in windows 8](http://www.howtogeek.com/137083/how-to-add-scan-with-windows-defender-to-the-context-menu-in-windows-8/) then you can easily scan a single file or folder. Check the link it is well explained with images.

Reproducing the information below:

> ## How to Add “Scan with Windows Defender” to the Context Menu in Windows 8
>
> [image: scan-with-windows-defender-from-context-menu]
>
> Windows Defender replaces Microsoft Security Essentials in Windows 8,
>   but it does not include the ability to quickly right-click folders and
>   scan them. However, you can add this option yourself with a quick
>   registry hack.
>
> This trick adds a “Scan with Windows Defender” option to the context
>   menu that appears when you right-click a folder. It works similarly to
>   the “Scan with Microsoft Security Essentials” option on previous
>   versions of Windows.
>
> Unfortunately, there is no command that launches Windows Defender in
>   graphical mode and initiates a scan, so we will have to launch Windows
>   Defender in a Command Prompt window.
>
> ### Add the Context Menu Entry Manually
>
> Press the Windows key to access the Start screen, type regedit at the
>   Start screen, and press Enter to launch the Registry Editor.
>
> [image: launch-registry-editor-on-windows-8]
>
> Navigate to the following key:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell
> ```
>
> Right-click the shell key in the left pane, point to New, and create a
>   new Key. Name it **WindowsDefender**.
>
> [image: create-windows-defender-key-in-registry]
>
> With the WindowsDefender key selected in the left pane, right-click in
>   the right pane and create a new String value. Name it **Icon**, then
>   double-click it and enter the following value:
>
> ```
> %ProgramFiles%\\Windows Defender\\EppManifest.dll
> ```
>
> Right-click in the right pane again and create another new String
>   value. Name it **MUIVerb**, then double-click it and enter the
>   following value:
>
> ```
> Scan with Windows Defender
> ```
>
> [image: scan-with-windows-defender-in-registry]
>
> Right-click the WindowsDefender key in the left pane, point to new,
>   and create a new key. Name it **Command**.
>
> [image: windows-defender-command-subkey]
>
> Double-click the (Default) value in the right pane with the Command
>   key selected and give it the following value:
>
> “C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe” -scan -scantype 3
>   -SignatureUpdate -file %1
>
> [image: windows-defender-scan-command]
>
> When you use the option, you will see the scan happen in a Command
>   Prompt window. You will only be alerted if a problem is found. If the
>   scan is very quick, you will see a Command Prompt window appear and
>   disappear quickly. If a problem is found, the window will alert you
>   instead of closing.
>
> [image: windows-defender-scan-in-command-prompt]

Comment: While this is a very complete answer, for those who don't want to start a click orgy, here are two .reg files that do the same: http://blog.dummzeuch.de/2015/11/28/add-a-scan-with-windows-defender-context-menu-to-any-folder-or-file/

Comment: Worth mentioning that this only works on *folders*, not individual files. (also for some reason I can't get my entry for `(default)` to save)

Comment: When activating it, it doesn't show a window or dialog. Does it not work or is it silent? Would be nice to get a confirmation;

Answer (score 1):

**Scan with Windows Defender** has finally been added to Right-click menu.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click > Scan with windows defender

Found a few more tricks to [scan with windows defender using cmd & Powershell.](https://gamespec.tech/how-to-scan-with-windows-defender/#7-method-5-scan-with-windows-defender-command-line)